# Cannot find module node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'

Tags: android, react-native

After using expo eject i tried to run my app on android emulator:

```
PS C:\Users\becim\OneDrive\Počítač\test> yarn android
yarn run v1.22.5
$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1296 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\becim\OneDrive\Počítač\test\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\becim\OneDrive\Počítač\test\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\becim\OneDrive\Po��ta�\test\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 195
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:928  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\becim\OneDrive\PoÄŤĂ­taÄŤ\test\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:15)    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\becim\OneDrive\Počítač\test\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Any solution to this?

Comment: Please edit your question to format code and error statemements as codeblocks

Answer (score 2):

It is happening because of your path. Move your project to english-based path

Comment: thanks man, i spent weeks trying to solve it and finally your answer fell from the sky, thank youuuuuuuuu =)

Answer (score 1):

Delete your  node modules directory and run this command :

npm install

Comment: it gives me the same error except theres one more line after "info Installing the app..." Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details